# next page in additional page in Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Why I can't go to next page in parse_next and merge some date do object?

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = TItem()
    ...
    link_www = lekarz.xpath('whatever/@href').extract_first()
    request = scrapy.Request(link_www, callback=self.parse_next)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

    next_page = response.css('whenever::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

attri = []

def parse_next(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    self.attri.append(xpath("whatever")).extract_first

    next_pager = response.css('whatever_too_xd').extract_first()
    if next_pager is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_pager, callback=self.parse_next)
    else:
        item['hehe'] = self.attri
        yield item
```

OUTPUT:

KeyError: 'item'

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the item to the callback. To do so, just add `meta` argument to `response.follow` invocation:

```
response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse_next, meta={'item': item})
```